# SPARK error: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am running with hadoop 2.7.0 version, scala 2.10.4, java 1.7.0_21 and spark 1.3.0

I have created a small file as below

```html
hduser@ubuntu:~$ cat /home/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt
Eid1,EName1,EDept1,100
Eid2,EName2,EDept1,102
Eid3,EName3,EDept1,101
Eid4,EName4,EDept2,110
Eid5,EName5,EDept2,121
Eid6,EName6,EDept3,99
```

And getting the error while running the below commands.

```html
scala> val emp = sc.textFile("/home/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt")
emp: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /home/hduser/test_sample/sample1.txt MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:21

scala> val dept = emp.map(_.split(",")).map(r => r(3))
dept: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:23

scala> dept.collect().foreach(println)
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
```

Could you please suggest exactly what I have to do in this case.

Comment: It seems your Spark version is not compatible with the Hadoop version you have...? Can you make sure that the Spark version you have is compatible with the Hadoop version ?

Comment: Could you please let me know where I can find the table to check the compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at spark download page. "https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html".
There are Spark distributions pre-built for different Hadoop versions.

Comment: It resolved after installing spark 1.3.1 for hadoop 2.6 or later version.